# Mango grows on a mango tree or mango grows in a mango tree?

Tags: grammar

Which preposition is used after grow if it indicates the growth of a fruit on a tree?

Comment: Fruit grows _on_ trees, as you have written yourself. There's a familiar expression _Money doesn't grow on trees_ (meaning that it isn't just there for the asking).

Answer (score 2):

Fruit grows *on* trees.

After climbing it, then you could be sitting *in* a tree.